# Verificar se arquivo existe por 20 segundos C#

Tags: c#, .net, timer, stream-de-arquivos

Estou fazendo um módulo que trabalha com troca de arquivos e na documentação pede para aguardar 20 segundos pelo arquivo de status xxxxxxxx.sta, porém, não sei como implementar isso em C#. Estava tentando algo nessa linha, mas parece que roda de forma assíncrona, assim não consigo pegar o resultado *bool* se o arquivo existe ou não na hora que eu quero:

```
public void ValidarArquivoStatus(int numeroSequencialDoArquivo)
{
    seq = numeroSequencialDoArquivo;
    aTimer = new Timer(1000);
    aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    aTimer.AutoReset = true;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;

}

private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Principal.ValidouArquivoDeStatus = false;
    previousTime = e.SignalTime;
    //int tempoMaximoTentativaExecucao = Convert.ToInt32(Funcoes.LeParametro(14, "7", false));
    int tempoMaximoTentativaExecucao = 20; 
    if (ExisteArquivoDeStatus(seq))
    {
        //aTimer.Enabled = false;
        Principal.ValidouArquivoDeStatus = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = false;
    }
    nEventsFired++;
    if ((nEventsFired == tempoMaximoTentativaExecucao) || (Principal.ValidouArquivoDeStatus == true))
    {
        aTimer.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual a assinatura do método ao qual você realiza a verificação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levando em consideração que o seu método de validação não é assíncrono, irei assumir que você precisa verificar de 20 em 20 segundos se existe um arquivo em um determinado diretório.

Seguindo sua linha de raciocínio o código abaixo executa o método `DoWork()` através do `timer_Elapsed`.

Ao final da execução do `DoWork()`, o timer é "reiniciado" (`finally`) e o `DoWork()` é chamado novamente.

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace LearnTemporizador
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Timer timer;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            timer = new Timer();

            timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;

            timer.AutoReset = false;

            timer.Enabled = true;

            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20).TotalMilliseconds;

            timer.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void DoWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Validou! {Validar()}");
        }

        private static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DoWork();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                timer.Start();
            }
        }

        private static bool Validar()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado deu certo assim!

Comment: @SidneiSanches, show! :D

Answer (score 0):

Se for só para aguardar esse tempo, pode usar o timer da thread.

basta adicionar o código abaixo antes da verificação do arquivo:

```
Thread.Sleep(20000);
```

Observação:
Caso não esteja usando, necessário fazer o import abaixo:

```
using System.Threading;
```